# Searching with Knockout.Js using ASP.Net

Tags: knockout.js

Im having problems get my search to work. I would like to be able to update the original list after a search for first name has been entered.

My JavaScript

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.police = ko.observableArray();
  self.error = ko.observable();
  self.detail = ko.observable();


  var policeUri = '/api/polices/';

  self.getPoliceDetail = function(item) {
    ajaxHelper(policeUri + item.Id, 'GET').done(function(data) {
      self.detail(data);
    });
  }

  function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    return $.ajax({
      type: method,
      url: uri,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      self.error(errorThrown);
    });
  }

  function getAllPolices() {
    ajaxHelper(policeUri, 'GET').done(function(data) {
      self.police(data);
    });
  }

  // Fetch the initial data.
  getAllPolices();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

My HTML for the search box. I have a simple data bind like such for my html.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: police">
  <li>
    <strong><span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span> <span data-bind="text: LastName"></span></strong> : <span data-bind="text: Gender"></span>

    <input type="search" class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: query" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Do you want the search box to work client or server side? What have you tried already? What do your data look like?

Comment: I want it to work client side similar to a live update. I have binded my data to a observable for knockout but its not filtering the data. Once I call getallpolice, if a person was to search for a police, I would just like to filter those results and update the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you'll have to add the `query` property you've bound to your search input to your viewmodel:

```
self.query = ko.observable("");
```

Now, you can make a `computed` property that subscribes to changes in the `police` array, *and* to the `query` observable. Knockout manages the dependencies for you: if you evaluate an observable inside a computed's method, it makes sure it's always up to date!

```
self.filteredPolice = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  var searchQuery = self.query();
  var currentPolice = self.police();
  var filteredPolice = [];

  // TODO: filter the actual results

  return filteredPolice;

});
```

From your HTML snippet I see the objects in `police` have a `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Gender` property. I can imagine you'd want to search in both first and last name. Let's fill in the `// TODO`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentPolice.length; i += 1) {
  var current = currentPolice[i];
  if (current.FirstName.indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1 ||
      current.LastName.indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1) {
    filteredPolice.push(current);
  }
});
```

Now, you'll have to make sure you `foreach` the computed array:

If you want to only search `x` milliseconds after the last keypress, you can extend your `query`:

```
self.query = ko.observable().extend({ 
  rateLimit: { 
    timeout: 200, 
    method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" 
  } 
});
```

I'd suggest you test this code and make sure you understand all of it. Then, we can do some refactoring and make some improvements (of which some might be a matter of personal preference).

**The main problem with the code above** is that it does not cover most of the search possibilities. Right now, it looks for an *exact* match in *either* the first, *or* the last name. So "John Doe" will not match `{ FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" }`. If you're not sure how to solve this, I'd suggest looking up some different questions concerning client-side searching in javascript. I tried to focus on the "knockout approach" in this answer.

---

*Separate search logic*:

I'd suggest to creating some sort of utility function or `PersonViewModel.contains` method to contain the search logic. Or make it even more generic and do something like this: (note, it's in ES2015)

```
// Note: Case insensitive & not optimized for performance
var objContainsStringInProps = function(str, props, obj) {
  var lowerStr = str.toLowerCase();
  return props
    .some(key => {
      var value = obj[key];   
      return value && (typeof value) === "string" &&
        value.toLowerCase().includes(lowerStr);
    });
};
```

*Using the generic method in the computed*:

Your computed can then be:

```
self.filteredPolice = ko.pureComputed(() => {
  // Create a new method in which only the `obj` param is required:
  var policeItemSearchMethod = objContainsStringInProps
    .bind(null, self.query(), ["FirstName", "LastName"]);

  return self.police()
    .filter(policeItemSearchMethod);
});
```